# Apps Script Library Security

Tags: security, google-apps-script

I am wondering about the security of apps script libraries. If a user imports a library, is there any way for them to retrieve the code within the library?

I ask because I am writing a library that connects many sheets to a single sheet which acts like a database. Users of the many sheets should not be able to find the database sheet.

I have tested console logging the functions, and they just return [Function] and not the actual function definition. However I still don't know if this is a safe implementation or not. Would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other users to use your library, you have to give them access by sharing the script.

Authorized users can view the function code by printing the function or going to the script link

**Using print:**

[image]

**Using script link:**

`https://script.google.com/d/(Script ID Here)/edit`

---

In your post above, you want to hide any data that will lead users to database sheet.

I suggest to create a temporary function in your library script that will set a property containing the Sheet ID. This can be done by using **Properties Service**. Using this service will allow you to store strings as key-value pairs scoped to one script.

**Example:**

```
function setProperty(){
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("Sheet_ID", "123456");
}
```

**Usage:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var databaseID = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("Sheet_ID");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetId(databaseID)
}
```

**Note:** *Before deploying your library script, run the `setProperty()` function and delete it in your script editor. This will prevent users from viewing the source code for `setProperty()` function. Also, make sure that the role of the users you will authorize to access your library is **Viewer** only to prevent them from editing your script and printing the Property value.*

### Reference:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)

Comment: Hi @Nikko J, this is extremely helpful! I should have added more context. All of the instances of the sheet will be created by 1 account which will act as a service account between those instances and the database sheet. The data will be transferred using time based triggers setup by that "service account". That being said, your tip with setProperty is really really good to know and I will be using that. Thanks so much!